# ¿como puedo llamar un metodo de una Clase hija para usarla en un metodo de una clase Padre?

Tags: c++

en la estructura del void de mi clasepadre quiero llamar el void que esta en la clasehija... ¿eso es posible?

```
class clasepadre{ 

private:
    atributo;
public:
    void funcion1();
};

class clasehija::clasepadre{

private:
    atributo2;
public:
    void funcion2();
};

void clasepadre::funcion1(){ //este es el void en donde quiero llamar otro void

//aqui quiero llamar a "void funcion2" que se ubica en la "clasehija"
//no se como hacerlo.
}
```

si quieren mas detalles me avisan

Comment: Inicialmente como lo planteas no. Pero se podría hacer que la clase padre sea abstracta, obligando a que la hija declare un método. De esta manera podrías llamar desde la clase padre a un método de la clase hija

Comment: Puedes usar polimorfismo. Marcando una función como `virtual`.

Comment: No es posible, porque la herencia es una jerarquia unidireccional, pues, para que las clases hijas puedan heredar los atributos y metodos de su padre este debe ser declarado y definido primero y despues vienen todas aquellas clases que pueden heredar de él, y como no hay clases hijas por encima de la clase padre este no puede llamarlas simplemente porque no las conoce, creo que tu problema tiene que ver con como estas ideando la solucion, se me hace raro que veas la necesidad de usar una clase base (padre) para realizar una tarea que bien puede hacer la clase hija, porque las ha heredado no?

Answer (score 4):

Como poder ... se puede. Ahora bien, que sea lo que esperas, o que sea útil en tu escenario concreto ... eso es otra historia.

Lo que pretendes es algo lo suficientemente común para tener patrón propio, con un nombre que *me encanta*: [`Curiously recurring template pattern (Patrón de plantilla curiosamente recurrente)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

El *caso-de-uso habitual* de este patrón es permitir que las clases hijas **proporcionen la implementación** de una (o varias) funciones *a* la clase padre. Lo cual va en contra de lo que se espera en POO, y del uso de la herencia ... pero eso es justamente lo que tú pretendes y lo que se consigue:

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T > struct clasepadre {
    void funcion1( ) {
        std::cout << "Se ha llamado a 'clasepadre::funcion1( )'\n";
        static_cast< T * >( this )->funcion2( );
    }
};

struct clasehija : public clasepadre< clasehija > {
    void funcion2( ) {
        std::cout << "Se ha llamado a 'clasehija::funcion2( )'\n";
    }
};

int main( ) {
    clasehija ch;
    ch.funcion1( );

    return 0;
}
```

Si compilamos y ejecutamos el código anterior, obtenemos:

> Se ha llamado a 'clasepadre::funcion1( )'
> Se ha llamado a 'clasehija::funcion2( )'

Como ves, el *truco* es curioso ... *y recursivo*: declaramos una clase hija, que hereda de una clase base templatizada y cuyo argumento de plantilla es la clase hija, (que hereda de una clase base templatizada y cuyo argumento de plantilla es la clase hija, que hereda ...).

Esto es posible porque las plantillas solo se instancian **cuando se usan realmente**. En este caso, el **uso real** se produce dentro de `main( )`, y el compilador ya ha *pasado* tanto por `clasepadre` como por `clasehija`, conociendo lo necesario de ambas.

Observa también que en la llamada **real** ha sido necesario *convertir* `this` a un puntero al argumento de plantilla `T`.

```
 static_cast< T * >( this )->funcion2( );
```

Esto es posible porque hay relación de herencia entre `T` y `clasehija`, y generaría un error de compilación en otro caso.

Answer (score 2):

No existe la visibilidad de clases base a clases derivadas porque una clase base no sabe qué clases derivarán de ella. Por lo tanto no se puede hacer lo que pides, ya que no puedes llamar funciones que no sabes que existen.

Pero puedes forzar que existan:

```
class clasepadre {
    atributo a;
public:
    void funcion1();
    /* Esta funcion esta declarada en 'clasepadre' y obliga a todas
       las clases derivadas a declararla, eso significa el '= 0'. */
    virtual void funcion2() = 0;
};

class clasehija :clasepadre {
    atributo2 a2;
public:
    void funcion2();
};

void clasepadre::funcion1() {

    /* Puedes llamar 'funcion2' porque sabemos que existe en cualquier
       derivada que tenga 'clasepadre'. */
    funcion2();

}
```